# why do changes to the armature made in edit mode vanish when I change modes?

Tags: armature, rigging

Sorry for the basic question!

I found out that my knees in the blender armature where not bending because I extruded them in a straight line. When I tried to create a bend in them in edit mode, the legs would revert to their straight position in edit and pose mode.

Why is this???

Comment: Do you have any keyframes on them?

Comment: wow that was fast! No I don't.

Comment: ahhh, sorry. I tried to unlock some of the inverse kinematics to stop the leg from bending incorrectly and I forgot to change that. Hope that made sense. This is all new to me. The knees are now bent in all modes but they still will not bend!!!

Comment: I did it from scratch with a bend in the knees from the get go and there is no problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike plain objects armature bones have two defined positions. The first position is known as the rest position (or rest pose) and is the position while in edit mode. While in pose or object mode the pose position is used. This pose position is the one that you keyframe to get animations.

While in pose mode any movements are retained as locations relative to the rest position, You can rotate a bone in pose mode then go into edit mode and move it sideways, it will also move sideways in pose mode but will also retain the rotation that was applied before the edit was made.

While in pose mode you can select bones as desired and clear any rotation or location changes to get the armature back to a rest pose with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> for location and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> for rotation.

In the armature properties you can also switch between rest and pose position to see any pose alterations.

[image]